# Eslint - Tab after line break

Tags: javascript, eslint

How can I set a rule for auto tabulating words that comes after a line break?

For example:

```
const {} = someReallyLongName123456789 ??
c;
```

Should be:

```
const {} = someReallyLongName123456789 ??
  c;
```